# Laravel 5.2 how can I get only the post data like $_POST?

Tags: laravel, request

I have tried `$request->all();` and `$request->input();` but both include  the `$_GET` data.

How can I retrieve only the `$_POST` data with Laravel?

Comment: There is no wrong with laravel.Do you want to display post data or insert?

Answer (score 7):

The `$request` has a `request` section which includes just the POST variables.

If you wanted just the `$_POST` variables you could use the following:

```
$request -> request -> all();
```

Similarly, there is a `query` section which includes just the GET variables.

You could retrieve just the `$_GET` variables with the following:

```
$request -> query -> all();
```

Comment: On a POST request, you should just have the POST data in $request -> request (I do in Laravel 5.2). It doesn't behave in this manner on a GET request, but on a GET request you already know there can't be any POST data.

Comment: Yes but i want get only the POST data, i want one function to give me only the POST without GET only the post

Comment: Make sure that you're testing this on a POST request. On a GET request the behaviour is different. But on a POST request `$request -> request -> all()` returns just the POST variables, and `$request -> query -> all()` returns just the GET variables.

Comment: No! The $request -> request -> all() returns me and the GET DATA try to see

Comment: No! I make my template engine but your answer is right! How can accept the answer?

Comment: You just need to use the tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: Isn't this a huge security risk? The official Laravel documentation doesn't mention this concatenation of both GET and POST values. For example a hacker on a registration form with a poorly designed backend handler could request the url with additional GET parameters that he guesses might give him more permissions.. Or am I seeing this completely wrong?

Comment: @SvenP he could also POST to the form handler with falsified data, it isn't that much more difficult. Validation of input no matter how it receives is the server's responsibility.